# Book about three kids who use a gate in a maze as a teleporter during World War 2

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a book 5 years ago about three kids, two boys and one girl, who lived in an orphanage during World War 1 or 2 or something like that. They found a teleporter in a maze, and they used it to to teleport to different places, but not times, and had to face the Germans and supernatural forces.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy.  You have some interesting details here, but it might help if you had a look at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/48874 , which provides some guidance about how to improve story identification questions to make them easier to answer.